# Simplest Qt Dialog

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, bluetooth, qml

I have a C++ function that checks if Bluetooth is activated. I want to display a simple dialog telling the user to activate his Bluetooth and try again. As I have a QML interface this can be done through C++ or QML.

Comment: This is not a place where people will just write your program for you.  You should make an honest attempt to do it yourself, then ask a question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in information message box:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Try Again", "Please try to activate your Bluetooth again.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Qt Components have some dialogs out of box:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-components-symbian-1.0/qml-querydialog.html